# MS Word expression

Tags: if-statement, ms-word, expression

I am try to make page numbers with IF statement like this

```
{ IF { PAGE } > 1 "{ PAGE }" "" }
```

And doing all like here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/95886

If more than one page than site numbers will show up. But i cant make it working when i press `CTRL + F9` and type this command its not working.
Even only `{ PAGE }` not working but when i put this command form menu its working... what i doing wrong?? Why its not working after `CTRL + F9.` and Typing `PAGE`.
I know that i can preview it by `ALT + F9`

Sorry for not English Screenshot

[image]

BEFORE `ALT + F9`:
[image]
AFTER `ALT + F9`:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the field after inserting it outside the header or footer.

To insert:

- Type Alt-F9 to switch on field display
- Type Ctrl-F9 to enter field
- Type PAGE to enter page field
- Type Alt-F9 to shut down field display
- Type F9 to update the fields

To manually add DATE:

- Type Alt-F9 to switch on field display
- Type Ctrl-F9 to enter field
- Type DATE to enter date field
- Type Space to add extra space, there should be 2 spaces! (enable display formatting if you want to see the spaces)
- Type Alt-F9 to shut down field display
- Type F9 to update the fields

As you can see, adding the right number of spaces in the formulas is critical. By adding the fields through the Ribbon (Insert, Text group, Fields) you can see how Word is creating the fields itself. If you are familiar with the formatting you can easily type Ctrl-F9 with the formula and update all with F9.

Comment: Thanks its working. Do You know how i can call `Developer>Controls>Rich Text Content field` as this expression??  I have this field in my document and user type content, but i want to put same content which user typed in footer as instance. How i can call it?

Comment: @Ponciusz It is a new question and should be entered as such in a new question, but take a look at this (the answer there): http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/mirror-text-entered-into-a-rich-content-control/64c941c1-1df5-4eff-b4cf-ccfba3c6f72b?db=5 You should be able to 'map' content controls to other places.